# Fitting image to UAModalPanel

Tags: objective-c, image, uamodalpanel

I'm currently using UAModalPanel and I just want show pictures with this component. So I did the following:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UAModalPanel.h"

@interface LolcatPanel : UAModalPanel

- (void)showLolcat;

@end


#import "LolcatPanel.h"

@implementation LolcatPanel

- (void)showLolcat
{
    int pic = (arc4random() % 10) + 1;
    NSString *intString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", pic];
    NSMutableString *picture = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:intString];
    [picture appendString:@".jpg"];
    NSLog(@"Loading image %@", picture);

    NSString* imageName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:intString ofType:@"jpg"];

    UIImage *testImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageName];

    if (testImage == nil) {
        NSLog(@"FAILED");
    }

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];
    imgView.image = testImage;
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

    [self addSubview:imgView];
}

@end
```

I want to show pictures fitting in the UAModelPanel, but ATM the results are not really good.

Comment: In what way are they 'not good' ? Don't make us guess what your problem is.

Comment: The problem is, that it doesn't fit in the shown popup, it just takes the whole space of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of the image view when it's displayed. You should also configure the auto-resizing / auto-layout so that it has a known reaction to the superview being changed.

You may want to switch to aspect fit instead of scale fill content mode to get a nice display. You may also need to set the image view to `clipToBounds` to prevent any drawing of the image outside the set bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(22, 20, width, height)];
imgView.image = testImage;
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

[self.contentContainer addSubview:imgView];
```

I had to add the imageview to the contentcontainer.

Regards,
Sascha